# Jensen gap for a real-valued random variable $X \geq 0$

Tags: inequality, jensen-inequality

For a real-valued random variable $X \geq 0$,

We have $1 - \frac{1}{1+E \left[x\right]} \geq E \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{1+x} \right]$ (Jensen's inequality).

We want to get a tight constant gap between $1 - \frac{1}{1+E \left[x\right]}$ and $E \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{1+x} \right]$, i.e., $ \lvert  1 - \frac{1}{1+E \left[x\right]} - E \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{1+x} \right] \rvert \leq \epsilon_0$.

Any hints for this inequality?

Answer (score 0):

Taylor expanding $\frac{1}{1+x}$ around $x = E[x]$ gives us
\begin{align*}
\text{Gap} &= \left|1 - \frac{1}{1+E[x]} - E\left[1 - \frac{1}{1+x}\right] \right| \\&= \left|E\left[\frac{1}{1+x}\right] - \frac{1}{1+E[x]} \right| \\
&= \left|\frac{1}{1+E[x]} - E\left[\frac{x - E[x]}{(1 + E[x])^2}\right] +  E\left[\frac{(x - E[x])^2}{(1 + E[x])^3}\right] - \cdots - \frac{1}{1+E[x]}\right| \\
&\le \frac{\text{Var}(x)}{(1 + E[x])^3}
\end{align*}

Comment: How can we guarantee $ | - E \left[ \frac{x - E[x]}{(1+E[x])^2} \right] + \cdots | \leq \frac{\text{Var}(x)}{(1+E[x])^3}$?

Comment: The first term $E[x-E[x]] = 0$ and the second term is $\text{Var}(x)/(1+E[x])^3$ Since the series is alternating and your random variable is always positive, the remaining terms only serve to decrease your sum, so we can truncate and leave with that inequality.

Comment: Notice that $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\frac{x^3}{1-x}$. This gives $\frac{1}{1+X}=\frac{1}{1+\mathbb E[X]}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\mathbb E[X]-X}{1+\mathbb E[X]}}=\frac{1}{1+\mathbb E[X]}(1+\frac{\mathbb E[X]-X}{1+\mathbb E[X]}+(\frac{\mathbb E[X]-X}{1+\mathbb E[X]})^2+(\frac{\mathbb E[X]-X}{1+\mathbb E[X]})^3\frac{1}{1-\frac{\mathbb E[X]-X}{1+\mathbb E[X]}})$.
This yields $\mathbb E[\frac{1}{1+X}]-\frac{1}{1+\mathbb E[X]}=\frac{\mathrm{Var}(X)}{(1+\mathbb E[X])^3}+\mathbb E[\frac{(\mathbb E[X]-X)^3}{(1+\mathbb E[X])^3(1+X)}]$. Why is the second part negative?

Comment: Also, notice that this is closely related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544525/smallest-constant-c-to-bound-mathbbe-tfrac1-overlinex-n-1-leq-c) question.

Comment: The argument given above is incorrect; you are essentially claiming that $$\Big|\frac{1}{1+x} - \frac{1}{1 + y}\Big| \leq \frac{(x-y)^2}{(1 + y)^3} \qquad \mbox{for any}~x, y > 0.$$ The above inequality is only true if $y \leq x$. In your application you have $y = \mathbb{E}[X]$ and $x = X$. Your inequality is only true if $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq X$. This can be seen from Matija's comment above. It is exactly in this setting that $(\mathbb{E}[X] - X)^3 \leq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rephrase the inequality as $|\mathbb E[\frac{1}{1+X}]-\frac{1}{1+\mathbb E[X]}|\le\varepsilon$, i.e. we look at $\varphi(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$. Let $X_n\in\{0,n\}$ with $\mathbb P(X_n=n)=1/\sqrt{n}$, then we have $\mathbb E[\frac{1}{1+X}]-\frac{1}{1+\mathbb E[X]}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\frac{1}{1+n}-\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{n}}$. Taking $n\rightarrow\infty$ shows that the gap tends to $1$. On the other hand, since $\varphi(x)$ is decreasing we have $0<\varphi\le 1$ and thereby $\mathbb E[\frac{1}{1+X}]-\frac{1}{1+\mathbb E[X]}<1$, whereas $\mathbb E[\varphi(X)]-\varphi(\mathbb E[X])\ge 0$ follows from Jensen's inequality, so the tight constant is $\varepsilon=1$. The above implies that the answer for a given expectation $\mathbb E[X]$ will still be trivial, given by $1-\varphi(\mathbb E[X])$. If the variance is additionally fixed, then an argument similar to the discussion of Hoeffding's inequality or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544525/smallest-constant-c-to-bound-mathbbe-tfrac1-overlinex-n-1-leq-c) question can probably provide a non-trivial tight constant.