# Smallest constant $C$ to bound $\mathbb{E}[\tfrac{1}{\overline{X}_n + 1}] \leq C~\tfrac{1}{\mathbb{E}[X] + 1}$?

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be random real-valued random variables in the interval $[0, a]$. Assume they are independently and identically distributed. Let $\mu = \mathbb{E}[X_i]$ denote their common mean.

Define their average $\overline{X}_{n} = n^{-1} S_n$ where $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Let $f(t) := (t + 1)^{-1}$.

**Question:** What is the smallest constant $C = C(a, n) \geq 1$ such that we have
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(\overline{X}_n)] \leq C~f(\mu)?
$$

It should be emphasized that the constant $C$ is universal: it is valid for any law of $X_i$, supported on $[0, a]$. It should be dependent only on $a, n$.

**Comments:**

- Necessarily $C \geq 1$. Note that by Jensen's inequality, we have the following inequality,
  $
  \mathbb{E}[f(\overline{X}_n)] \geq f(\mu), 
  $
  since $f$ is a convex function on the nonnegative reals.
- Additionally, I claim that $C \leq 1 + \tfrac{a}{n}$. I have a proof of this below. (I would also be interested if there is a simpler way to establish this. I tried, thinking I could possibly improve the constant, to obtain it by Taylor expansion of the function $f$ around $t = \mu$, but failed to recover it.)

> Let $X_{n+1}$ be independent of $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$, but identically distributed. Then
> \begin{multline*}
> \mathbb{E} [f(\overline{X}_n)] = \frac{n}{\mu} 
> \mathbb{E} \Big[\frac{X_{n+1}}{S_n + n}\Big] =
> \frac{n}{\mu} 
> \mathbb{E} \Big[\frac{X_{n+1}}{S_{n+1} + n} \frac{S_{n} + n + X_{n+1}}{S_{n} + n}\Big]
> \\\leq \Big(1 + \frac{a}{n}\Big) \frac{n}{\mu} 
> \mathbb{E} \Big[\frac{X_{n+1}}{S_{n+1} + n} \Big].\qquad \mbox{(1)}
> \end{multline*}
> Since $X_{j}$, $j \leq n + 1$ are exchangeable, we also have
> $$
> \mathbb{E} \Big[\frac{X_{n+1}}{S_{n+1} + n} \Big]
> = \frac{1}{n+1} 
> \mathbb{E} \Big[\frac{\overline{X}_{n+1}}{\overline{X}_{n+1} + n/(n+1)} \Big]
> \stackrel{{\rm (*)}}{\leq}  \frac{\mu}{(n+1)\mu + n} \leq \frac{\mu}{n} \frac{1}{\mu + 1}. \quad \mbox{(2)}
> $$
> Above, we have used Jensen's inequality in (*) with mapping $z \mapsto z/(z + n/(n+1))$ which is concave on the nonnegative reals. Combining bounds (1) and (2), we get a bound $C(a, n) \leq 1 + a/n$.

Comment: As you argued, the constant is already asymptotically optimal (for $a=o(n)$), nice proof! The only way I see to identify the *smallest* constant is to identify distributions for which the inequality holds with equality (or sequences of distributions that enforce it, but I think it is attained). This is fairly demanding, but I think it might actually be possible. What you want to do is to completely explain the Jensen gap, over all possible distributions.

Comment: Indeed, one way to interpret my question is to completely characterize the Jensen gap, which as you say is quite a strong requirement. For instance one could wonder if it is possible to replace $C$ by $1 + a/n^2$. This would also be asymptotically optimal in the sense that for fixed $a$, it is $1 + o(1)$ in the limit $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Secondly, I am wondering if there is a simpler proof of my claim $1 + a/n$. One could try to do this by Taylor expanding $\mathbb{E}[1/(\overline{X}_n + 1)] = 1 /(\mu+ 1) + \mathbb{E}[\xi^{-3} (\overline{X}_n - \mu)^2]$. However, the difficulty is that $\xi$ is random in the sense that it lies between $\overline{X}_n$ (random) and $\mu$.

Comment: The constant $C$ has to be valid for *any* distribution. It cannot be that you select $C$ based on the distribution.

Comment: I have added a few clarifying comments to emphasize this point.

Comment: Notice that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3249677/jensen-gap-for-a-real-valued-random-variable-x-geq-0) question addresses a similar topic.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the solution to the problem.
It turns out that the sharpest constant is in fact
$$
C(a, n) = 
\sup_{\lambda \in [0, 1]}
\sum_{j=0}^n \frac{\lambda n a +  n }{ja + n} \lambda^j (1-\lambda)^{n-j} \binom{n}{j}.
$$

---

We use $\mathsf{Ber}(p)$ and $\mathsf{Bin}(n ,p)$ to denote
the Bernoulli and Binomial distributions with parameter $p \in [0, 1]$ and positive integer $n$.

Let $Y_i = a~\mathsf{Ber}(X_i/a)$.
Define the sums
$$
S_n = X_1 + \dots + X_n, \quad \mbox{and} \quad 
T_n = Y_1 + \dots + Y_n.
$$
Note that $\mathbb{E}[T_n \mid X_1, \dots, X_n] = S_n$.
Additionally, note that $T_n = a~\mathsf{Bin}(n, \lambda)$ in distribution, where $a\lambda = \mathbb{E}[X]$.

Therefore, using the convexity of the map $t \mapsto (n + t)^{-1}$,
we have

$$
\frac{\mathbb{E}((1 + \tfrac{1}{n}S_n)^{-1})}{(1 + \mathbb{E}[X])^{-1}} = \frac{n~\mathbb{E}((n + S_n)^{-1})}{(1 + \mathbb{E}[X])^{-1}}
\leq 
\frac{n~\mathbb{E}((n + T_n)^{-1})}{(1 + \mathbb{E}[X])^{-1}}
= \frac{\mathbb{E}((1 + \tfrac{1}{n}T_n)^{-1})}{(1 + \mathbb{E}[Y])^{-1}}
$$
This implies that with $f(z) = 1/(1+ z)$,
$$
\sup_{X:X \in [0, a]~a.s.} \frac{\mathbb{E}(f(\overline{X}_n))}{f(\mathbb{E} X)} 
= 
\sup_{\lambda \in [0, 1]} \frac{\mathbb{E}[f(\tfrac{a}{n}~\mathsf{Bin}(n, \lambda))]}{f(a \lambda)}.
$$
The right hand side is equal to
$$
\sup_{\lambda \in [0, 1]}
n(1 + a\lambda) \sum_{j=0}^n \frac{1}{ja + n} \lambda^j (1-\lambda)^{n-j} \binom{n}{j}.
$$
This proves the claim.

**Addendum:** The original post claimed that the optimum in the variational expression above is attained at $\lambda = 1/2$. This is false. It is not actually possible to compute the optimum analytically (to my knowledge).

Comment: Nice! This is a cleaner solution. I haven't seen this trick (of defining and using the $Y_i$'s) before. Let me explain what I had in mind and what the difference between our two answers is. What I had in mind was a "smoothing" argument, where you show in a "smooth" fashion that $X$ being a Bernoulli random variable is best (you could also assume you have are working with a maximizer $X$ and do a proof by contradiction). As a toy example, say we wanted to minimize $x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2$ subject to $x_1+\dots+x_n = 1$ and $0 \le x_i \le 1$ for each $i$. We claim the minimum is $\frac{1}{n}$,

Comment: obtained by having each $x_i = \frac{1}{n}$ (of course this can be proved immediately from Cauchy-Schwarz but never mind that for now). We can prove this by taking any $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ satisfying $x_1+\dots+x_n = 1$ and $0 \le x_i \le 1$ for each $i$ and supposing that some $x_i \not = x_j$; say $x_1 > x_2$ for concreteness. We may then define $(x_1',\dots,x_n')$ by $x_1'=x_1-\epsilon, x_2' = x_2+\epsilon$, and $x_i' = x_i$ for $3 \le i \le n$, where $\epsilon \in (0,\frac{x_1-x_2}{2})$. Then $x_1'+\dots+x_n' = 1$, $x_i' \ge 0$ for each $i$, and a brief computation shows

Comment: $(x_1')^2+\dots+(x_n')^2 < x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2$. Therefore, we can "smoothly" transform any $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ into (the minimizer) $(\frac{1}{n},\dots,\frac{1}{n})$ (or we can assume the initial $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a minimizer and get a contradiction from $(x_1',\dots,x_n')$). [As a remark, this kind of proof is used to establish the characterization of eigenvalues as solutions to the optimization problem $\sup_{||v||_2 = 1} v^T M v$.] By analogy, what your proof does is jump *immediately* from $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to $(\frac{1}{n},\dots,\frac{1}{n})$; i.e., you go from $X_i$ to $Y_i$ in one step.

Comment: I think the denominator in your first inequality is $1/f$ instead of $f$, but that's not a problem for the proof since it's just a constant.

Comment: @p.s. fixed, thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

I think a smoothing argument shows that the maximum is attained for the random variable $X$, where $X = a$ with probability $1/2$ and $X=0$ with probability $1/2$. This yields$$C(a,n) = \frac{n(2+a)}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{ka+n}{n \choose k}.$$

---

Let's start with $n=1$ (and arbitrary $a > 0$).

Fix $\lambda \in [0,1]$. We claim the maximum of $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]$ over all rv's $X$ on $[0,a]$ with $\mathbb{E}[X] = a\lambda$, is attained when $X = a$ with probability $\lambda$ and $X = 0$ with probability $1-\lambda$.

We quickly note that the above claim resolves the $n=1$ case, since $(1+a\lambda)\left(\lambda\frac{1}{1+a}+(1-\lambda)\right)$ is maximized when $\lambda = 1/2$, no matter what $a$ is.

Anyways, the claim follows from a smoothing argument. Indeed, the inequality $$\frac{1}{1+b} < \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+(b-\Delta)}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1+(b+\Delta)}$$ holds for any $0 < \Delta < b$. Therefore, any "mass" of $X$ strictly between $0$ and $a$ can be broken up by moving half of it down a bit and half of it up a bit, preserving $\mathbb{E}[X]$ while increasing $\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{1}{1+X}\right]$.

---

Hopefully the above is rigorous for you enough. It's not too hard to make it (more) rigorous.

The same argument should work for any $n \ge 1$; I know that the maximum still occurs at $\lambda = 1/2$, though the analogue of that centered inequality (to reduce to the optimization over $\lambda$ problem) becomes a bit more complicated, though shouldn't be too bad (I'll do it later).

Comment: Interesting. I am not sure I completely follow your smoothing argument. However, if correct it is interesting to note that your $C(a,n)$ is able to be written as $\tfrac{n (2 + a)}{2} \cdot \mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{aX + n}]$, where $X \sim \mathsf{Bin}(n, 1/2)$. Using the heuristic $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{aX + n}] \approx \frac{2}{(a+2)n}$ would give $C(a,n) \approx 1$. In other words, if your claim is correct, it seems the order of approximation is much better than $a/n$ as my previous bound indicates.

Comment: @DrewBrady Do you understand it for $n=1$? If not, I can try to add some details.

Comment: Does your argument work by considering a random variable $Y = a$ when $X \geq x_0$ and $Y = 0$ otherwise, for some $x_0$?

Comment: $\lambda \in [0,a]$ should be $\lambda \in [0,1]$, no?

Comment: @leonbloy yea, thx

Comment: @DrewBrady That seems like a different proof, but thanks for it! Do you know what I mean by "smoothing"?

Comment: @DrewBrady Did you see " Therefore, any "mass" of  strictly between 0 and  can be broken up by moving half of it down a bit and half of it up a bit, preserving [] while increasing [11+]."

Comment: @mathworker21 I do not think the maximum actually occurs at $\lambda = 1/2$ in general. I just looked at this again, and plotted the function appearing in my comment over $\lambda$ for large values of $n$. The maximum occurs at something strictly smaller than $1/2$. Do you agree? What is wrong here?

Comment: @mathworker21 I can totally follow your smoothing argument for $n=1$, but things start to look far more complicated even for $n=2$. Even under the (yet to be proven) assumption that $X$ is some Bernoulli distribution, the values $0$ and $a$ with probability $1/2$ might no longer be optimal, since $\bar{X}_{2}$ then attains the values $0, a/2, a$ and $f(a/2)$ is rather small. Another Bernoulli distribution might be better for increasing $\mathbb{E}[1/(1+\bar{X}_{2})]$ and I don't see how your smoothing argument would work.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but builds on the argument of mathworker21.

The goal of this extended comment is to show a "simple" proof of the claim that
$$
C(a, 1) = \Big(1 + \frac{a}{2}\Big) \Big(\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1+a} + \frac{1}{2}\Big). 
$$

To show this claim, it suffices to show that the constant above can be placed in the following inequality for $C$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] \leq C~f(\mathbb{E} X), \quad \mbox{where}~f(t) = (1+t)^{-1},~\qquad\mbox{(*)}
$$
where $X$ has any distribution supported on $[0, a]$. (This is because we know that $C(a, 1)$ is attained for $X$ taking values $\{0, a\}$, equiprobably.)

Then (*) follows from Grüss-inequality [see Cor. 4, 1], which says that for any random variable $X$ and measurable functions $\phi, \psi$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E} \phi(X) \mathbb{E}[\psi(X)] \leq \mathbb{E}[\phi(X) \psi(X)] + \frac{(M_\phi - m_\phi) (M_\psi - m_\psi)}{4}. 
$$
Above, $m_\phi \leq \phi \leq M_\phi$, and $m_\psi \leq \psi \leq M_\psi$.

To see how (*) follows, take $\phi = f, \psi = 1/f$. Then we have
$$
M_\phi = 1, \quad m_\phi =  (a+1)^{-1}, \quad 
M_\psi = a + 1, \quad m_\psi = 1.
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(f(X)) \leq \Big(1 + \frac{a^2/(a+1)}{4} \Big) f(\mathbb{E}(X))
= C(a, 1) ~f(\mathbb{E}(X)).
$$
This proves the claim.

[1] Xin Li, R. N. Mohapatra, and R. S. Rodriguez. *Gruss-Type Inequalities.* Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications 267, 434–443 (2002).